# Storing Object Into Array Help Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make a appointment project which you can add, display, delete appointments.

I have three classes: `UserInput`, `Appointment`, `Planner`.

- `UserInput`: is just to promote the user to enter whatever ( `int`, `double`, etc..)
- `Appointment`: has set and get methods. two constructor, `toString`, and a method that user the `UserInput` class and then use the set methods with the value entered.
- `Planner`: is the class I have the options to delete, display and add appointments.

I created an array object of `Appointment` with 20 slots in the planner class.`private Appointment[] array = new Appointment[20];`

The problem I am facing is with adding objects to the array. I tried assigning default value for some slots in the constructor. I displayed the array and it worked. Now I made a method to call the `inputAppointment`( the class that ask the user to input then call the set methods ) method and assign what ever was inputted.

The method looks like

```
public void addAppointment() {
    Appointment object = new Appointment();
    object.inputAppoitment();
    array[5] = object;
}
```

inputAppointment method

```
public void inputAppoitment() {
    UserInput Object = new UserInput();

    System.out.println("Enter The Month");
    setMonth(Object.getString(3, 3));
    System.out.println("Enter The Day");
    setDay(Object.getInt(1, 31));
    System.out.println("Enter The Hour");
    setHour(Object.getInt(1, 24));
    System.out.println("Enter The Minute");
    setMinute(Object.getInt(1, 59));
    System.out.println("Enter A Short Description");
    setMessage(Object.getString(5, 40));

}
```

I ran the method then displayed the array but nothing was added!
I may seem made it too complicated but if you want something more clear I would be happy to explain.

**Update:**
I tried calling the method from main not my menu loop and it seems to work.
this is how my menu look like.

```
while (true) {
        System.out.println("\nPlease Choose.");
        System.out.println("A)dd Appointment , D)elete Appointment , L)ist Appointment , E)xit");
        char userChoice = UserInput.getChar();
        Planner obj = new Planner();
        if (userChoice == 'A' || userChoice == 'a') {
            obj.addAppointment();
        }
        if (userChoice == 'D') {

        }
        if (userChoice == 'L') {
            obj.listAppointment();
        }
        if (userChoice == 'E') {
            break;
        }

    }
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Completel, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what kind of variable here `array[5]` is? why are you storing `object` Object of Appointment in `array` > Please post your `inputAppointment()` Method and `Appointment`Class Code.

Comment: @VikrantKashyap for array[5] I was just trying to store object in that slot. array is the array object I declared.

Comment: @Heb23 can you post the array declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the scope of the object.

```
public void addAppointment() {
     // this would be unreferenced when the method finishes
    Appointment object = new Appointment();
    object.inputAppoitment();
    array[5] = object; // so now array[5] refers to object;
} // object is no longer in scope, array[5] no longer has a reference to it
```

I would rewrite your code like this:

```
public Appointment addAppointment() {
    // we have to access the reference when the method returns
    Appointment object = new Appointment();
    object.inputAppoitment();
    return object; // we return the reference to object and asign it into array[5]
}
```

We call it like this:

```
array[5] = addAppointment();
```

Comment: @Heb23 BTW, it might be better to rename your variables in a more descriptive way. That is, it might be hard for someone to know that "object" is actually an Appointment object. And a variable called "array", arrays of what?

Comment: yea that's something to keep in mind as a newbie. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend that you use java swing. It pretty much is just drag and drop for making UI, it gets pretty tough to make UI without it. Moving on to the array.

```
        Integer[] myArray = new Integer[20];
```

But I would recommend you use a list instead.

```
          ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
```

Let me give you some tips here. An array is like an oreo package. Every oreo (instead of integers, strings or and other type) has slots that they go into. And an oreo package can only hold so many oreos. **You must specify how many objects go into an array when you instantiate it (create it).** A list is like a Mary Popins Grocery bag. You can put in oranges, oreos, apples, and w/e. Also you can put as many things as you want in the bag. If you want you can specify to any level of detail what you want in the bag (list), so

```
   List<MyType> myList = new ArrayList<MyType>();
```

Now like I said before, try using a list instead of an array. Only use an array if you are sure of how many items will be in the array. For example if you were simiulating a deck of cards, you know it would be fifty two (not counting the jokers and ect...). Most people are going to recommend that you use an arraylist. I know it can be intimidating at first, but give it a try. Also I am going to assume you don't understand inheritance and polymorphism which is OK if your learning. But you need to understand that in programming you are building objects. Then all of these objects go into your main (for beginners at least).

Ok so before you get going **you need to use java swing** you will spend ten hours (at least when your first learn, soon it will be 15 minutes) using swing than opposed to 100 hours doing it by hand. I will use swing right now and get you a popup window and several other bits of funcitnaility in just 15 min.

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
 import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;

public class UserInput extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_2;
private JTextField textField_3;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                UserInput frame = new UserInput();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Appointment test = new Appointment();
            test.setAppointment("w/e you want, maybe the stuff from the windos...");
            test.addToMyList("once again, w/e you want, thurs 10:30, march...");
            System.out.println(test.Appointment);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public UserInput() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblEnterInfo = new JLabel("Enter Info Month");
    lblEnterInfo.setBounds(158, 11, 92, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblEnterInfo);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(147, 36, 115, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblEnterDay = new JLabel("Enter Day");
    lblEnterDay.setBounds(170, 67, 61, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblEnterDay);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setBounds(147, 92, 115, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblEnterHour = new JLabel("Enter Hour");
    lblEnterHour.setBounds(37, 123, 61, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblEnterHour);

    textField_2 = new JTextField();
    textField_2.setBounds(37, 148, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField_2);
    textField_2.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Enter Minute");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(272, 123, 61, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    textField_3 = new JTextField();
    textField_3.setBounds(261, 148, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField_3);
    textField_3.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblEnterShortDescription = new JLabel("Enter Short Description");
    lblEnterShortDescription.setBounds(147, 179, 120, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblEnterShortDescription);

    JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
    editorPane.setBounds(127, 204, 150, 46);
    contentPane.add(editorPane);
}
}
```

And the other class,

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Appointment {

private ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
String Appointment;



public String getAppointment() {
return Appointment;
}




public void setAppointment(String appointment) {
   Appointment = appointment;
}




public ArrayList getMyList() {
    return myList;
}




public void setMyList(ArrayList myList) {
    this.myList = myList;
}




public void addToMyList(String x){
    this.myList.add(x);
}

}
```

Trust me man. Learn java swing. Then learn what it means to instantiate an object. Then learn the difference between lists and arrays. No one learns programming overnight. Took us all 6 months to a few years to really learn java.

Comment: I did tried arraylist but it seems the problem not from my method because i ran the method from main and it worked but I ran it from my menu loop it didn't work. My menu code is up there.

Comment: @bob dude how does java swing compare to c#'s winforms?

Comment: Wish I knew. I am a java, python, and mysql programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Arraylist concept for add object into Array.
List list=new ArrayList();
Appointment object = new Appointment();

using list method you can add delete or retrieve value according your need.
list.add(object);

Comment: I tried that it worked if I call like it from main like call the method then call the list method to make sure it got sorted it works. But If I run the menu then choose A that call the method then call L to make sure that it got stored into array it doesn't work.